# Error while Installing MongoDB on AWS Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

The error is:

Public key for mongodb-org-3.4.4-1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm is not installed

I am trying to install MongoDB as mentioned in official MongoDB documentaion [HERE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/).

Comment: So did you actually follow the instructions? Where are you getting the error? Which steps have you followed? Also see [Disable the public key check for rpm installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/288648/disable-the-public-key-check-for-rpm-installation)

Comment: After i run  sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution to remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try from this documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Step1: 
Download the binary files for the desired release of MongoDB.

Step2: 
Extract the files from the downloaded archive.

Step3: Copy the extracted archive to the target directory.

Step4: 
Ensure the location of the binaries is in the PATH variable.

Step5: 
Run MongoDB.

Comment: He wants to install it on Amazon(AWS) not on local!