# Error while installing mongodb on AWS using SSH

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install ***mongodb*** for my **MEAN** Stack Website on **A.W.S.** .
For this I am following it's official documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/).

After this(`sudo yum install -y mongodb-org`) step I am getting this error.
The error is:

I have searched for this error on *google* and *stackoverflow* and found the similar problem but not exact, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223612/error-while-installing-mongodb-on-aws-amazon-linux).

```
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: openssl
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: openssl
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: rtld(GNU_HASH)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: rtld(GNU_HASH)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: rtld(GNU_HASH)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: openssl
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.2.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.4)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-shell-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: rtld(GNU_HASH)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-tools-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.4)
           Requires: libssl.so.10()(64bit)
```

Before this error I have these dependencies completion:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) for package: mongodb-org-too
ls-3.4.14-1.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.am
zn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn
1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: mongodb-org-server-3.4.14-1.amzn
1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

In step of configuring the packet manager the below line path was given,

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo
```

But there was no `yum.repos.d` directory in etc instead it was `yum/repos.d/` , so I made a file in it `mongodb-org-3.6.repo` and entered information as given on site.
I have tried different versions to install it and made different files and eventually removed them.

I have tried other ways also for installing mongodb on A.W.S like, from [here](https://github.com/SIB-Colombia/dataportal-explorer/wiki/How-to-install-node-and-mongodb-on-Amazon-EC2).
The other site I found to install was [this](https://optimalbi.com/blog/2017/09/14/how-to-install-mongodb-with-aws-ec2/).
But here I was getting error after `sudo apt update` as:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-170:~$ sudo apt update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list (
Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I found out that the link they are using in the previous step is giving 404, so I tried different combinations manually and found this the modified link `https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse/` , I tried changing it and updating but still got some different error.
Can anyone provide the solution to remove above errors or a method to install it(**mongodb**) on **A.W.S.** using **ssh**(*ubuntu*).